# VS Looks for Headerfile in Debug folder

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

I am really new to C++ and in haven't worked with VS in a long time.

My problem is, VS suddenly throws me an error when I try to import one of my header-files that is in the same folder as the cpp file I try to import it in.

[image]

Maybe I hit some Keycombo or klicked on a "bad" button ^^
I also checked my "Additional Includes Folder"-Setting it only points to my other projects src folder. If I clear the value it the error still persists.

I feel like its weird that VS looks for the header in the Output folder (but it's also looking for a .tlh whatever that is)

Thanks :)

Comment: `#include` not `#import`

Comment: By design.  The odds that you meant to **import** a type library are vanishingly small.  You want to **include** a .h file, so use `#include`.

Comment: Thanks guys, I feel so stupid now. I guess that's the first and last time this will happen to me (*hope)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just change `#import "Game.h"` to `#include "Game.h"`.

[Import directive](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/preprocessor/hash-import-directive-cpp?view=vs-2019) is used for type libraries not header files.

Keeping in mind the fact, these files (`tlh`) are generated by the compiler, so its actually not *weird* that VS looks them in output folders.